# Translations in Lightning Web Component

Tags: lightning, community, lightning-experience, lightning-web-components, multi-regional

I have to build a Lighting Web component which would be exposed to the Lightning community for guest user License. 
I want this component to be multi-lingual. The language will be passed in the URL. 
Basically I will be using language translation workbench for the translation. Example the picklist values will be translated in Translation workbench and based on the language in the URL I need to show the corresponding values.
Is that something possible?

Thanks in advance